# how to implement json in realm swift

Tags: swift, realm

I have a dictionary in json format. I want to show it with a table in my app(about 1000 cells) and also save it to realm database. I am new to database can anyone please tell me how to implement this? Should I try to convert the format outside the app or load the json when it is used?

My dictionary looks like this..

```
[  
   {  
      "id":0,
      "book":1,
      "lesson":1,
      "kanji":"\u4e2d\u56fd\u4eba"
   }   {  
      "id":1,
      "book":1,
      "lesson":1,
      "kanji":"\u65e5\u672c\u4eba"
   },
   ...
]
```

Comment: Please post some structure of your dictionary.

Comment: parse the JSON and extract keys to make realm model accordingly. also realm documentation is easy to understand , I would recommend to dive into it.

Comment: That looks like just a basic Dictionary with key: value pairs for each child Dictionary. So create a Realm object with 4 properties [Realm Model](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#models), pass the child Dictionary (id, book, lesson, kanji) to the Realm object (via init, or a function) to populate it's properties and save it to Realm. Is there something more?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you will need to install 2 pods:

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON' #great for handling JSON
pod 'RealmSwift' #Realm database
```

You will need to create the object that will be able to be saved in Realm. I suppose your object is some type of course or something similar. You can rename it per your needs:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import SwiftyJSON

class Course: Object {

   @objc dynamic var id = 0
   @objc dynamic var book = 0
   @objc dynamic var lesson = 0
   @objc dynamic var kanji = ""

   override static func primaryKey() -> String? { //you need this in case you will want to update this object in Realm
      return "id"
   }

   convenience init(courseJson: JSON) {

      self.id = courseJson["id"].intValue
      self.book = courseJson["book"].intValue
      self.lesson = courseJson["lesson"].intValue
      self.kanji = courseJson["kanji"].stringValue
   }    
}
```

Now, at the place where you get your json from the server, you need to do this:

```
var courses = [Course]()
let jsonArray = JSON(dataFromServer).arrayValue
for courseJson in jsonArray {
   let course = Course(courseJson: courseJson)
   courses.append(course)
}

//Now, you need to save these objects in Realm:

let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(courses, update: true)
}
```

In the viewDidLoad method of the view controller where you want to show the data, you need to fetch all your Course objects from Realm, add them to an array and show data in the tableView/collectionView:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class PresentingCoursesVC: UIViewController {

   //MARK: IBOutlets
   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

   //MARK: Properties
   var courses = Results<Course>?

   //MARK: Lifecycles
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      getCourses()
   }

   //MARK: Private functions
   private func getCourses() {
      let realm = try! Realm()
      courses = realm.objects(Course.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "id", ascending: true)
      tableView.reloadData()
   }
}

//MARK: TableView Datasource
extension PresentingCoursesVC: UITableViewDataSource {

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

      return courses?.count ?? 0
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomCell") as! MyCustomCell
      let course = courses[indexPath.row]
      cell.setupCell(course: course)
      return cell
   }
}
```

I hope my answer was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Book: Object {
  @objc dynamic var id = 0
  @objc dynamic var book = 0
  @objc dynamic var lesson = 0
  @objc dynamic var kanji = ""
}

class MyDic: Object {
    var yourKeyOfDic = List<Book>()
}
```

Now map your dic with `MyDic` class object and then add that object in realm by following code,

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
  realm.add(yourDicObject)
}
```